# Is the estimator $\frac{\overline X}{1-\overline X}$ of $\theta$ consistent?

Tags: probability-theory, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

> Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample from a population having the probability density function $$ f(x;\theta) = \begin{cases} \theta x^{\theta -1} & \text{if $0 \le x\le$ 1} \\0 &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Is the estimator $\hat\theta =\dfrac{\overline X}{1-\overline X}$ of $\theta$ a consistent estimator of $\theta?$

I am trying to find $E(X) $ here to see if it is equal to $\theta$ asymptotically but I am not sure how to find expectation here I am not familiar with finding $E(X)$ of fractions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to find $E(X) $ here to see if it is equal to $\theta$ asymptotically

It's not $E(X)$ that should be equal to $\theta$ asymptotically, it's $\hat{\theta}$.

Let's find $E(X)$ as you suggest $$E(X) = \int_0^1 xf(x;\theta) \ dx = \int_0^1 \theta x^{\theta} = \frac{\theta}{\theta+1}   $$

Now let's see in the asymptotic regime how $\hat{\theta}$ behaves,
$$\hat{\theta} = \dfrac{\bar X}{1-\bar X} \rightarrow \frac{E(X)}{1-E(X)} = \frac{\frac{\theta}{\theta+1} }{1-\frac{\theta}{\theta+1} } = \frac{\theta}{\theta+1} \frac{\theta+1}{1} = \frac{\theta}{1} = \theta $$
So, what can you say about $\hat{\theta}$ ?

Comment: seems like our estimator is not consistent but my textbook says it is .

Comment: Hey @Damandeep, yes it is not asymptotically consistent .. what does your textbook say?

Comment: see here http://www.math.louisville.edu/~pksaho01/teaching/Math662TB-09S.pdf You can see last question of 16th chapter and answers on last page it says yes it is consistent

Comment: Yeah because they got another estimator which is $\hat{\theta}  = \frac{\bar{X}}{1- \bar{X}}$ .. in your question you have a plus sign instead of a minus in the denominator .. makes a WHOLEEE lot of difference.

Comment: omg I am so dumb i am so sorry

Comment: no worries, i have edited your question and my answer .. please see now :) @Damandeep

Comment: change title too

Comment: no need @Damandeep .. question is still the same ;) .. btw if you found the answer useful you can mark it as correct as well

Comment: Don't we need to check if $V(\hat \theta)=0 $?

Comment: how can $V(\hat{\theta}) = 0$ if $\hat{\theta}$ is itself random .. unless you mean in the asymptotic regime, maybe ?

Comment: Yes as our sample size approaches $\infty$

Comment: An estimator is consistent if, as the sample size increases, the estimates "converge" to the true value of the parameter being estimated. That's it. What you mention ($V(\hat{\theta}) = 0$) is a consequence of certain types of consistent estimators.

Comment: The statement you said is very much familiar with statement of Law of large numbers is there any realation between them?

Comment: yup .. we have used LLN here, when we said $\bar{X} \rightarrow E(X)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Forgive me for not mentioning it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the answer is *no*. Perhaps we may do as follows.

Denote
\begin{align}
S_n&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nX_j,\\
T_n&=\frac{S_n}{1+S_n}.
\end{align}
Let us use the strong law of large number (SLLN) and the dominated convergence theorem (DCT) to go for the consistence.

For one thing, each $X_j\in\left[0,1\right]$ implies that $S_n\in\left[0,1\right]$. Consequently, $T_n\left[0,1/2\right]$, which implies that $\left|T_n\right|\le 1/2$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This upper bound $1/2$ is obviously integrable under the probability measure, i.e., $\mathbb{E}(1/2)=1/2<\infty$.

For another, by SLLN,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\mathbb{E}X_1=\frac{\theta}{1+\theta},
$$
which thus leads to
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}T_n=\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n}{1+\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n}=\frac{\theta}{1+2\theta}.
$$

Combine the above two facts, and DCT applies. This gives
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}T_n=\mathbb{E}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}T_n\right)=\mathbb{E}\frac{\theta}{1+2\theta}=\frac{\theta}{1+2\theta}\ne\theta.
$$
Therefore, $T_n$ is not a consistent estimator of $\theta$.

However, I suppose there might be a typo in $T_n$. In fact, if we consider another estimator
$$
U_n=\frac{S_n}{1-S_n},
$$
the answer would be *yes*.

The scope of its proof is essentially the same as above, although some tricks are necessary. This is because DCT would fail as $U_n$ is no longer bounded from above (more precisely, it is not trivial to figure out some $V$ such that $\mathbb{E}V<\infty$ and that $\left|U_n\right|\le V$).

To help facilitate our proof, define
$$
U_{mn}=U_n\cdot 1_{\left\{U_n\le m\right\}}.
$$
Note that $U_n\ge 1$ is guaranteed because $S_n\in\left[0,1\right]$. Besides, note that $U_{mn}$ is monotone in $m$, i.e.,
$$
U_{mn}\le U_{m+1,n}.
$$
Thanks to these two facts, the monotone convergence theorem (MCT) applies. It gives
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\lim_{m\to\infty}U_{mn}\right)=\lim_{m\to\infty}\mathbb{E}U_{mn}.
$$
Consequently,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}U_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\left(\lim_{m\to\infty}U_{mn}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}\mathbb{E}U_{mn}.
$$
Further, for each fixed $m$, $\mathbb{E}U_{mn}$ converges as $n\to\infty$ by DCT, and for each fixed $n$, $\mathbb{E}U_{mn}$ converges uniformly as $m\to\infty$ due to the uniform cutoff. These facts inspires that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}\mathbb{E}U_{mn}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}U_{mn}.
$$

Thanks to all these arguments, we may safely conclude that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}U_n=\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}U_{mn}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}U_{mn}\right)=\cdots=\theta.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your effort

Comment: @Damandeep: No problem :-)